# The login page I'm testing lets me in as long as the username starts with the right name. How could the SQL query be made?

Tags: sql-injection

Let's say my username is ***theusername*** and my password is ***thepassword***. If use those credentials I login as expected. However if I add whatever at the END of the username, say ***theusername.random.stuff.at.the.end***, I still get to login to my account. Doesn't work if I do that at the beginning.

Also, if I put an odd number of single quotes at the end whether I add the other random stuff or not (Example: ***theusername'*** or ***theusername.random'''***), it won't let me in. Won't match any username in the DB. It will let me in if the number of single quotes is even though.

And lastly, if the username ends with a single quote and double dash (Example: ***theusername'--***) it will take it as a valid username (It matches the username in the DB) but will say the password is wrong even if I submit the actual password.

I know when a submitted username matches an username in the DB because the page shows a different error for when the username is bad and when the password is bad.

My question is... Knowing they are using T-SQL, what query string are they possibly using?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does whatever you add at the end of the valid username have to begin with a dot?

Comment: It is also worth noting that some companies allow users to be a bit fluffy with their usernames and passwords e.g. Facebook announced that they allow users to have spelling mistakes at the start and end of their username or password.

Comment: @MikePoole It's not a company. It's my schools website.They have a few other bad practices sprinkled around the website. They trust the client with sensible information. I guess they don't expect anyone to be that curious.

Comment: Hi Pedro. I am not surprised to hear that schools do a similar thing. It is worth noting that such fuzziness does not necessarily make the security much less secure. It is also worth noting that your school would not like you hacking them unless they have given you permission to do so. Stay curious, but stay legal.

Comment: @MikePoole I know it's been months but only now I'm seeing your first question. No, whatever I add at the end of the valid username doesn't have to begin with a dot.

Comment: It seems like it isn't secure against SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to know the precise SQL query without seeing the code, but the following is plausible, but a stretch:

1. SQL

> select * from users where username='{0}' and password='{1}'

2. Server-side Code:

Perhaps instead of validating input, this system is instead trying to sanitise. We can assume that passwords are not sanitised for dots (have you tried dots in your password?)

2a. Because of the '.' behaviour, let's assume that the code (PHP?) is grabbing the first bit of text before the first '.' character.

2b. Because of the even behaviour, let's assume that the code (PHP?) is filtering out evens only (using a loop with Replace("''", ""))

3. Database type

I assume the database is Postgres, where '' is the valid escape-character sequence. For MySQL it's '

Test cases:

1. theusername.random.stuff.at.the.end [success]

- Sanitised username = theusername
- Unchanged password = mypassword
- Final SQL: select * from users where username='theusername' and password='mypassword'
- Expected Result: Success

2. random.stuff.at.the.start.theusername [login fail]

- Sanitised username = random
- Unchanged password ='mypassword
- Final SQL: select * from users where username='random' and password='mypassword'
- Expected Result: Fail (Record doesn't exist)

3. Odd number of single quotes: theusername' [fails]

- Sanitised username = theusername'
- Unchanged password = mypassword
- Final SQL: select * from users where username='theusername'' and password='mypassword'
- Expected Result: Fail (Invalid Syntax)

4. Even number of single quotes: theusername'' [succeeds]

- Sanitised username = theusername
- Unchanged password = mypassword
- Final SQL: select * from users where username='theusername' and password='mypassword'
- Expected Result: Fail (Invalid Syntax)

5. Odd number of single quotes with double-dash: theusername'-- [says the password is wrong]

- Sanitised username = theusername'--
- Unchanged password = mypassword
- Final SQL: select * from users where username='theusername'--' and password='mypassword'
- Expected Result: Multiple rows (for some reason - maybe a bug that results in multiple username records being created with different passwords - perhaps over time? perhaps upon each password change?)
- The server-side code gets multiple records and it processes them in a loop looking for a mismatch - it finds the mismatch on one of the records (even though there is a match, it isn't looking for a match) and response with the "wrong password" message.

Hopefully, this will help as a scratchpad for others to find a more plausible explanation. I don't like the server-side code assumptions, nor the multi-row assumption for test [5].